# How would I set out these simple tables with primary keys etc in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I’m trying to create a relational database whereby I can award students ‘Awards’ throughout their time at school. I have chosen mySQL to do this and have a system ready as soon as I have sorted the database out properly.

I *think* I have these tables correct, however I’m not sure which would be the primary/foreign/indexes (if they are even needed)

I will have 10 Awards that I will award, and one student could earn all ten over their time at the school.

Am I correct in thinking the tables should look something like this:

**Student**

- StudentID
- FirstName
- Surname
- SchoolYear
- Form

**Awards**

- AwardID
- AwardTitle
- AwardDescription

How would I “link” these together on MySQL properly? So that I can assign multiple awards to students?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have a third table of student_award. Perhaps schoolyear and form will start to seem like they need to be in a table of their own too.

Comment: It's called a "many-to-many" relationship. look it up.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. Would the many-to-many go between the Student ID and Award ID? I have been reading other examples for a while, but can't figure out which way around it goes.

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach here would be to make a 'link' table, lets say AwardedStudents and within it to have:

```
AwardRowID PK
,StudendID FK reference Student(StudentID)
,AwardID FK reference Awards(AwardID)
```

So later on, you are going to be able to join on both criteria

**EDIT:**   You can omit the AwardRowID column if there is no way one student to be awarded with the same AwardID (because this will lead to duplicating rows) and simply make composite PK from StudendID and AwardID. But if this is possible situation, you need to stay with the AwardRowID PK in the table.

Comment: Excellent, would the only PK in the database be the AwardRowID, or would I also set the StudentID and AwardID as PK's in their own tables?

Comment: They should be a PK also, if they are unique, the same is valid for AwardRowID. So if you have a Student, that will have two awards of the same ID, then you need to remove the PK from AwardRowID.

Comment: Great, they will only be getting one Award with the same ID. 

CREATE TABLE pledges
(
pledgeid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (pledgeid)
);

CREATE TABLE students
(
studentid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (studentid)
);

CREATE TABLE studentspledges
(
pledgerowid INTEGER,
studentid INTEGER,
pledgeid INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (pledgerowid)
);

ALTER TABLE studentspledges ADD FOREIGN KEY (studentid) REFERENCES students (studentid);

ALTER TABLE studentspledges ADD FOREIGN KEY (pledgeid) REFERENCES pledges (pledgeid);